# Set project variables for Visual Studio Code

Tags: projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-code

When I load an existing Visual Studio project in Visual Studio Code, I get errors because the project files refer to variables ("properties"?) that are not set properly by Visual Studio Code.

For example `$(VisualStudioVersion)` seems to be set to `10.0`, so I get errors like this

> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported
>   project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   c:\SvnWork\HM.Plan.ProductPlan\HM.Plan.ProductPlan.Web\HM.Plan.ProductPlan.Web.csproj

From project content like this

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="'$(ExpectedTypeScriptIsInstalled)'=='true'" />
```

How do I set variables like `$(VisualStudioVersion)` in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the similar issue with Microsoft.WebApplication.targets by adding the explicit override from 10.0 to 14.0

```
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0'">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
```

However, this is definitely a matter of change in future VS code versions. Why 10.0?